# Sticky Nav Header with React Hooks and IntersectionObserver API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

Basically my goal is to translate this StickyNav implementation to ReactJS and keep the cross-browser compatibility:
https://codepen.io/smashingmag/pen/XWRXVXQ

The main problem I have is to find the proper way to implement the `direction` and `prevYPosition` variables with react hooks.
I added all my setup for the IntersectionObserver and the rest of the helper methods within a `useEffect` hook, and tried to store the values for direction and prevYPosition using `useState`.
But when I add those variables to the useEffect dependencies it's causing the component to re-render multiple times and the original logic simply doesn't work.

So, what I did as my first implementation attempt was to store the `direction` and `prevYPosition` variables in the actual header (bc I had a reference to that node thru `useRef`). But it doesn't fulfill all the use cases. It works properly when you scroll up and down. But when you click on a link element on the Nav trying to jump from section 1 to section 4 it doesn't work as expected. You can see that implementation here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sticky-nav-i4e0y

I would highly appreciate if someone can provide me some guidance on how to approach this implementation to make it work properly with react js.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From your question, i thought you are facing problem with the scrolling. so use debounce to resolve this issue.

Some of the debounce sources are:

1. Lodash debounce - https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce
2. useDebounce hook - https://usehooks.com/useDebounce/

Comment: Hey Ranganath MD, I don't think that's the problem here. As you can see I added an example of my current implementation now:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sticky-nav-i4e0y

The good thing about using the IntersectionObserver API is that you aren't actually listening to every scroll event. And instead, it fires only when one of the observed elements is intersecting with the viewport based on the options that you provided.